# Biber not producing any output file

Tags: biblatex, biber, output

Biber is said to have many advantages for those writing in languages other than English but I have been unable to get the results I used to have with bibtex. I have Lyx 2.0.5.1, biblatex 1.7, and biber 0.9.9.

In my example the citation will show up but not the list of references. This is probably due to the fact that Biber fails to produce a `.bbl` output although it claims to do so. But why?

Example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,headings=normal]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true,bibencoding=auto]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{Egg1975.bib}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Test (\citealt{Egg1975}, 89 Fn.~1)
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

.bib:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.8.1.
% Encoding: ISO8859_15
@ARTICLE{Egg1975,
  author = {Egg, Rudolf E.},
  title = {{S}ozialtherapie in {E}rlangen: {M}ethoden und erste {A}uswirkungen
    einer {V}ersuchs- und {E}rprobungsanstalt},
  journal = {Bewährungshilfe},
  year = {1975},
  volume = {22},
  pages = {87-102},
  hyphenation = {german},
  owner = {adessec},
  timestamp = {2012.12.11}
}
```

.blg:

```
[0] Config.pm:300> INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
[0] Config.pm:303> INFO - Logfile is 'TestBiberMWE.blg'
[1] biber:145> INFO - === Do Jan 10, 2013, 13:46:34
[1] Biber.pm:271> INFO - Reading 'TestBiberMWE.bcf'
[20] Biber.pm:586> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[31] Biber.pm:2585> INFO - Processing bib section 0
[50] Biber.pm:2677> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Egg1975.bib' for section 0
[79] bibtex.pm:708> INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/home/adessec/texmf/bibtex/bib/Egg1975.bib'
[112] Biber.pm:2480> INFO - Sorting list 'MAIN' keys
[112] Biber.pm:2484> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE.UTF-8'
[126] Biber.pm:2480> INFO - Sorting list 'SHORTHANDS' keys
[126] Biber.pm:2484> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE.UTF-8'
[128] bbl.pm:427> INFO - Writing 'TestBiberMWE.bbl' with encoding 'ascii'
[128] bbl.pm:498> INFO - Output to TestBiberMWE.bbl
```

Comment: Does ``bibtex`` run without errors on the same file? If yes, could you please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and provide also a piece of your ``.bib`` file that reproduces the error? Oh and [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to see the log file Biber has produced.

Comment: Your code works for me (using one of my `bib` files). By the way, you use an old version of `biblatex` and `biber`. Also, using the `natibib` option makes redundant to declare the `natbib` commands (`\citet`, `\citep`).  You can use `\citep[89 Fn.~1]{Egg1975}`, and the `\noindent` is useless.

Comment: In some cases, Biber isn't able to start its run because of an internal error that has a rather simple fix. Please, add the contents of the `.blg` file you find in the working directory.

Comment: @Benedikt: `bibtex` runs without any errors on the file after appropriate changes. I reduced the code for a MWE.

Comment: @Joseph and @egreg: `.blg` added as well as `.bib`.

Comment: @AxelDessecker I've tried with a TeX distribution having Biber 0.9.9 and the resulting `.bbl` file exists and is not empty.

Comment: Did you run latex again after biber? Also you need to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` because of the characters in your `bib` file.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes I did run `latex` after `biber` but this is rather useless as the `.bbl` does not exist. I thought about file encodings before but I don't think utf8 is required here.

Comment: @egreg: My TeX distribution is texlive as provided by opensuse.org for OS 12.2. This is of course the most recent stable version.

Comment: @AxelDessecker I needed the input encoding when I tried it on my set-up to avoid same utf8 characters not being printed.  But it seems you have a more fundamental problem.  Perhaps you should upgrade your system.

Comment: @Guido: The most convenient workaround for me at the moment is to stick to `bibtex8`. I guess upgrading `biblatex` and `biber` independently would raise to many other issues.