# Biber failes to validate

Tags: installing, texlive, biber

I installed Biber 1.7 and biblatex 2.7a from the opensuse Publishing:/TeXLive/ [repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Publishing:/TeXLive/openSUSE_12.2/). As the [problem posted earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91036/biber-not-producing-any-output-file) - no `bbl` output is produced although `biber` pretends to do so - persists, I tried to validate `biber` using the [test files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/testfiles/):

```
adessec@ipek:~/Dokumente/Privat/EDV> biber --validate_control --convert_control test
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
ERROR - 'test.bcf' failed to validate against schema '/tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/bcf.rng'
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Here is `biber` output without any extra options (the final info that `test.bbl` was written is misleading):

```
adessec@ipek:~/Dokumente/Privat/EDV> biber test
INFO - This is Biber 1.7
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.0, expected version 2.5
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
Use of uninitialized value $label in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
Use of uninitialized value $label in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'test.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'test.bib'
WARN - Labelname candidate 'author' is not a name field - skipping
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE.UTF-8' default tailoring 'level = 4' with 'level = 2'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de_DE.UTF-8' default tailoring 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'MAIN' keys
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de_DE.UTF-8'
Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber.pm line 1926.
Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber.pm line 1940.
Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber.pm line 1943.
Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber.pm line 1944.
INFO - Writing 'test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.2 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup
\refsection{0}
Use of uninitialized value in string comparison (cmp) at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 493.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 494.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 494.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 494.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 494.
Use of uninitialized value $label in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
Use of uninitialized value $label in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
Use of uninitialized value $label in string eq at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.
  \sortlist{entry}{MAIN}
    \entry{test1}{book}{}
      \field{sortinit}{s}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
Use of uninitialized value $listlabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 508.
Use of uninitialized value $listlabel in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/par-adessec/cache-1810d1114b7baebb573cdb31a20722a23dce204b/inc/lib/Biber/Output/bbl.pm line 510.
  \sortlist{entry}{}
    \entry{test1}{book}{}
      \field{sortinit}{s}
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput

INFO - Output to test.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 2
```

Removal of the temporary directory will not help. This will just regenerate as soon as `biber` is launched again. Any ideas?

Comment: You have `biblatex` 2.7 installed, don't you?

Comment: We need to see the biber output without any extra options, just `biber test`

Comment: `@karlkoeller`: `biblatex` 2.7a is there.

Comment: `@PLK`: output added

Comment: `@PLK`: The problem is solved by the most recent `texlive-
biber-2013.72.1.6svn30591-72.1` package. The minimal example now works. `biber test`, however, still produces two warnings.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by a bug fix (see comments).